# Cant get C program and strsep() and getenv() to all work together

Tags: c

I had this working before, but I was using pointers. getenv() keeps crashing so I copied the results using sprintf(). Now I want to deliminate with : and print only the first occurrence. Please help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(void) {

    char buf[999];
    const char *token;

    // HTTP_PROXY == 8.8.8.8:8888, end result should print 8.8.8.8

    sprintf(buf, "%s", getenv("HTTP_PROXY"));
    *token = strsep(&buf, ":");
    printf("New result: %s\n", token);

}
```

Comment: 1. network is hard. 2. network is very hard in C 3. network is impossible if you don't know how to search. 4. network is impossible in C for beginner 5. maybe this list is too long 6. maybe you don't want to do network in C, and just want to parse a string

Comment: Note that using `strsep()` on the result of `getenv()` modifies the environment; it is not a good idea to do that.  Make a copy of what `getenv()` returns before mangling it with `strsep()` or `strtok()` or …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `strsep` wants a pointer to pointer, you must pass a pointer to pointer, not a pointer to array. This is *not* the same thing; make a pointer, and assign it `buf`. Pass a pointer to that new pointer to `strsep` to fix the first problem.

The second problem is that since `strsep` returns a pointer, you need to assign it to `token`, not to `*token`:

```
char buf[999];
const char *token;
// HTTP_PROXY == 8.8.8.8:8888, end result should print 8.8.8.8
sprintf(buf, "%s", getenv("HTTP_PROXY"));
char *ptr = buf;           // Since ptr, is a pointer...
token = strsep(&ptr, ":"); // ...you can pass a pointer to pointer
printf("New result: %s\n", token);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char const *http_proxy = getenv("HTTP_PROXY");
  if (http_proxy == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "HTTP_PROXY not set: default 8.8.8.8:8888");
    http_proxy = "8.8.8.8:8888";
  }

  char *cpy = strdup(http_proxy);
  char *token = strtok(cpy, ":");
  if (token == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "wrong format");
    return 1;
  }
  do {
    printf("Token: %s\n", token);
  } while ((token = strtok(NULL, ":")) != NULL);
  free(cpy);
}
```